# How to set template for DataGrid with ItemSource as DataTable using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My XAML:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonTable}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"/>
```

My code in ViewModel:

```
PersonTable = new DataTable();
PersonTable.Columns.Add("Name");
PersonTable.Columns.Add("Delete");
```

I would like to get Button in AccessType column but:

```
DataRow dataRow = PersonTable.NewRow();
dataRow["Name"] = person.Name;
dataRow["Delete"] = new Button();
PersonTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
```

Which creates cell with 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' value. I would like to achieve same behavior like using this xaml:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

How to use template when using DataTable? How bind for eg. color in Person to Cell in DataGrid?

EDIT:
Delete columns is an example. I don't know columns names and count of columns in advance.

EDIT2: 
Because of misunderstanding: delete is only a example, I need to at 20 or more columns in runtime. I need to be able to put there buttons in cells and bind to properties.

Comment: Then you are better off with dynamic grid http://paulstovell.com/blog/dynamic-datagrid

Answer (score 0):

A neat and nice approach would be

```
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PersonTable}" 
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      CanUserAddRows="False" Grid.Row="1" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Delete">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Delete"
                                Command="{Binding SomeCommand,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                Margin="5"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

you can bind your command to delete button and perform actions.

Comment: I also need to do this for dynamic added columns so I don't know names of columns and theirs count.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom DataGridColumnTemplateSelector.
The template selector will return the template of each datagrid column based on predefined convention (ex: prefix of the DataTable column names).

that way the template will remain dynamic and cusutomized

Answer (score -2):

Your DataGrid :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="89,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Now, we will use dynamic loading of XAML. For that we need markup in a separate text file. Change its Build Action to Content, and Copy To OutputDirectory to Always.

myDataGridCol.txt :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn 
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ToggleButton Content="{Binding ^colname^}" Background="Red">
                            </ToggleButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Adding columns dynamically to DataGrid can be done like so :

```
foreach (DataColumn col in PersonTable.Columns)
            {
                DataGridTemplateColumn dtcol;

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(("32678595/DataGridTemplateColumn.txt")))
                {
                    String xamlContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    xamlContent = xamlContent.Replace("^colname^", col.ColumnName);

                    dtcol = (DataGridTemplateColumn)(System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(xamlContent));
                }

                dtcol.Header = col.ColumnName;
                MyDataGrid1.Columns.Add(dtcol);
            }

            MyDataGrid1.ItemsSource = PersonTable.DefaultView;
```

And binding Color to a cell can be done using concept presented below :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100" Header="Color">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
           <Label>
             <Label.Background>
               <SolidColorBrush x:Name="CellColor" Color="{Binding PropertyColor}"/>
             </Label.Background>
           </Label>
         </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Now, that you know how to add columns dynamically and to bind background property. You can make your ViewModel accordingly.

And you can use `Color col = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(value);` to convert String to Color for Binding ease.

And if you are using a String to store color value, then normal binding would work.

```
<Button Content="color" Background="{Binding PropertyColor}"/>
```

Comment: delete is only a example. I need to have 20 columns added at runtime and all of this columns must to be toogle button with binded command and color.

Comment: @senfen check my answer and give your comments please.